# Recommendations for books that provide a good survey of the history of mathematics, and are meant to be read by mathematicians/mathematics students?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Preferably:

1. The book should not be fixated upon the "standard/popular" accounts of the Greeks (which usually begin with Pythagoras, move on to Euclid and Aristotle, and end with Hypatia).
2. The book should be more concerned with achievements over the past 500 years.
3. The book should be aimed at an audience of mathematicians or mathematics students.

Comment: The historical notes of the Bourbaki treatise have been assembled in a single volume, although of course they might be somewhat dated if you also want to cover the very recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stillwell's *Mathematics and Its History* is an excellent book that fits your description perfectly. See [my review](http://www.amazon.com/review/RBKFN5I2ZI8TS).

Comment: I just read through a fair bit of the initial portions of the book, and I couldn't resist simply saying: *you're exactly right*. If I could checkmark your answer twice, I would. It does fit my description perfectly, and I heartily recommend it too to anyone who comes along in the future.